# How can I create a path with Bézier curves using a script?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, illustrator-scripting, bezier-curve

I have a script which makes a simple shape* for me:

```
var docRef = documents.add();
var piRef = activeDocument.pathItems;

{
    var pathRef = piRef.add();
    pathRef.setEntirePath( new Array(
        new Array(475,543.30078125),
        new Array(450,500),
        new Array(475,456.69873046875),
        new Array(525,456.69873046875),
        new Array(550,500),
        new Array(525,543.30078125),
        new Array(475,543.30078125) ) ) ;
}
```

However, the shape(s) which I create are limited to straight paths, how could I change this to be creating paths with curved edges?

I'm pretty new and inexperienced to Illustrator scripting, I'm sure there's a better way for me to be making this path in the first place.

---

I use [this script](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/100961/63979) from Wolff in order to **extract** my path coordinates (after creating the path in Illustrator), I assume I'd have to modify that as well in order to have it export round paths.

<sup>*The shape being a hexagon is irrelevant, the idea is to be able to create arbitrary shapes.</sup>

Comment: Welcome to the dark side.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with setEntirePath, you have to make a new pathItem (Document.pathItems.add()) and then you have to add your path points individually.

You would do this via:

```
var myPath = app.activeDocument.pathItems.add();

var newPoint = myPath.pathPoints.add();
newPoint.leftDirection = [10, -5];
newPoint.anchor = [0, 0];
newPoint.rightDirection = [-10, 5];
```

Now when you add more, this will form your Bezier curve!

---

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var myPath = doc.selection[0];
var pathPointArray = [];
var thisPoint;
for(var i = 0; i < myPath.pathPoints.length; i++){
    thisPoint = myPath.pathPoints[i];
    pathPointArray.push([
        [
            thisPoint.leftDirection[0],
            thisPoint.leftDirection[1]
        ],
        [
            thisPoint.anchor[0],
            thisPoint.anchor[1]
        ],
        [
            thisPoint.rightDirection[0],
            thisPoint.rightDirection[1]
        ]
    ]);
}
alert(pathPointArray.join("\n"));
```

Here's the result:

[image: The REAL result!]

And here's one where the entire thing is put together whereby it gathers the coordinates from your selection and creates a duplicate item of the same thing (without using copy/pasting or duplicate commands) exactly 100 points above the initial selection.

```
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var myPath = doc.selection[0];
    var pathPointArray = [];
    var thisPoint;
    for(var i = 0; i < myPath.pathPoints.length; i++){
        thisPoint = myPath.pathPoints[i];
        pathPointArray.push([
            [
                thisPoint.leftDirection[0],
                thisPoint.leftDirection[1]
            ],
            [
                thisPoint.anchor[0],
                thisPoint.anchor[1]
            ],
            [
                thisPoint.rightDirection[0],
                thisPoint.rightDirection[1]
            ]
        ]);
    }

    var myNewPath = doc.pathItems.add();
    var thisArrayPointObject;
    var newPoint;
    for(var i = 0; i < pathPointArray.length; i++){
        thisArrayPointObject = pathPointArray[i];
        newPoint = myNewPath.pathPoints.add();
        newPoint.leftDirection = [
            thisArrayPointObject[0][0],
            thisArrayPointObject[0][1] + 100
        ];
        newPoint.anchor = [
            thisArrayPointObject[1][0],
            thisArrayPointObject[1][1] + 100
        ];
        newPoint.rightDirection = [
            thisArrayPointObject[2][0],
            thisArrayPointObject[2][1] + 100
        ];
    };
```

And here is the result from that:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I can *extract* this data from a shape I've made?

Comment: I tried adding the code and got the error `myPath is undefined`, I'm definitely doing something wrong

Comment: Well you got to define it first, where did you think it was gonna come from?
Try doing this:
var myPath = app.activeDocument.pathItems.add();
That of course has to come before any of the stuff which acts on the variable called "myPath". But don't worry, you'll get it!

Comment: Use this exercise to collect pathPoints from one selected pathItem:

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var myPath = doc.selection[0];
var pathPointArray = [];
var thisPoint;
for(var i = 0; i < myPath.pathPoints.length; i++){
  thisPoint = myPath.pathPoints[i];
  pathPointArray.push([thisPoint.leftControl, thisPoint.anchor, thisPoint.rightControl]);
}
alert(pathPointArray.join("\n"));

Comment: The coordinates that it exports can't be used for a bezier curve, can they?

Comment: Oy, there was a BIG mistake in my snippet thing - the things aren't called "leftControl" or "rightControl", they are in fact called "rightDirection" and "leftDirection". Stay tuned for answer update!

Comment: Well, they in fact are coordinates for bezier curves. Each PathPoint object has your left/right directions, that's your control handles. The anchor is the 'actual' point, in the case of polygons you can think of them as bezier curves without any beziering since their 'control handles' are technically retracted to the same coordinates as the anchor points. As you can see in example, the left/anchor/right points are put into an array of 3-item arrays of 2-item arrays. You can use this array to add new PathPoints to a path you create.

Comment: Its perfectly valid to think of the control cage to be points of a bezier.

Comment: I was hoping to **export** the coordinates (using [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/100961/63979) script), what do I need to modify in order to do that?

Comment: Right now that script just takes into account the .anchor property to log the coordinates of the anchor, you will need to also incorporate the leftDirection/rightDirection points and then with whatever you would later draw the script with, you would have to consider those as well. It's basically the code I put into the answer - try to go from top to bottom and see what each line reads. With the understanding of this basic snippet could come untold super-user powers.